# Count only words, ignoring special characters in cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with columns contents some days of week abbreviate and underscores, separated by spaces, like this:

```
Mon ___ Wed ___ ___ ___
```

Tried some formulas like `=LEN(A1)-NÚM.CARAT(SUBSTITUTE(A1;" ";""))+1`, but doesn't returns only days.

I need count only this days, ignoring underscores and spaces. Is this possible using only formulas in excel 2016?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by replacing (substituting) the underscores with spaces and then use trim to remove duplicate spaces and then use the same logic you already had:

```
=IF(A1="",
    0,
    LEN(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_"," ")))
    -LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_"," "))," ",""))+1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can use this as well, using <kbd>FILTERXML( )</kbd> Function:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=COUNT(--(LEN(FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b"))=3))
```

---

Or, using the <kbd>Nodes</kbd> in <kbd>FILTERXML( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=COUNTA(FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b[count(node())>0]"))
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

```
=SUM(--(FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"_","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b[node()]")<>""))
```

---

To learn more on <kbd>FILTERXML( )</kbd> and its usages in Excel, a thorough analysis by **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir, can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml).

---